# xcode8 Alamofire 4 update error "use of undeclared type Response"

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, objectmapper

after updating to Xcode8 and Alamofire4 I am getting the error 'use of undeclared type Response' on the code "Response<[T]",  (which uses ObjectMapper and realm)

```
class FetchData {
static func get <T: Object> (_ type: T.Type, success:@escaping () -> Void,     fail:@escaping (_ error:NSError)->Void)->Void where T:Mappable, T:Meta {
    Alamofire.request(type.url(), method: .get)
    .responseArray { (response: Response<[T], NSError>) in
    //.responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[T], NSError>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let items):
                autoreleasepool {
                    do {
                        let realm = try Realm()
                        try realm.write {
                            for item in items {
                                realm.add(item, update: true)
                            }
                        }
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        fail(error: error)
                    }
                }
                success()
            case .failure(let error):
                fail(error: error)
            }
    }
}
}
```

I had the code working, to map data to realm using Object Mapper, as per this guide; https://blog.hyphe.me/realm-and-alamofire-in-a-effective-harmony/

Changing it to DataResponse did not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to Alamofire migration guide to version 4.0 [Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md), you should use DataResponse, so the commented line of code is actually right but have redundant parameter NSError which is included into DataResponse struct.
Fix:
`.responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[T]>) in`